# C++ discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, qualifiers

I have this error:

> BSPArduino.cpp:316: error: passing 'const BSPArduino' as 'this'
> argument of 'virtual void BSPArduino::enableWdt(const
> WATCHDOG_TIMER_DELAY&, const ___bool&)' discards qualifiers

This method is define like this:

```
void BSPArduino::enableWdt(const WATCHDOG_TIMER_DELAY &delay, const ___bool &enable)
```

I want to call it like this:

```
enableWdt(this->watchdogTimer, ___false);
```

With:

```
WATCHDOG_TIMER_DELAY watchdogTimer;
```

Why do I have this build error?

Comment: The calling context is const (eg void f() const { ... } )

Comment: You're calling a non-const method with an object that's const.

Answer (score 17):

BSPArduino::enableWdt() is a non-const method. If you try and call a non-const method from a const one you will get this error.

Essentially the error is trying to tell you that you are discarding the constness of "this".

Comment: The word of the day is... constness! Often used when describing adherence to [const correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#overview-const).

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to call a non-`const` function from a `const` member function; that's not allowed.

If possible, add a `const` qualifier to `enableWdt`. If that's not possible (because it modifies the object) then you'll have to either remove the `const` qualifier from the calling function, or restructure the code so that `enableWdt` is called from somewhere else.